# glm::ortho doesnt display anything

Tags: c++, glm-math

I need an orthographic projection matrix in OpenGL and I use glm for it like this:

```
glm::ortho(0.0f, width, 0.0f, height, zNear, zFar);
```

But this does not produce anything and I can't see anything on the screen. And yes, all of these values are floats.

I suspected it might be the view matrix, but I can render stuff when I use a perspective projection matrix.

Am I passing the wrong arguments? What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you do with the matrix returned by `glm::ortho`? What size are your objects? Are these just small dots in the viewport?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I use the matrix in the shaders as the projection matrix. The objects are either not visible or small dots at the edge of the screen.

Comment: So try something like `float aspect = (float)width/height;` and `glm::ortho(-aspect, aspect, -1.0f, 1.0f, zNear, zFar);`

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned by @Rabbid76 in the comments:

```
float aspect = (float)width/height;
glm::ortho(-aspect, aspect, -1.0f, 1.0f, zNear, zFar);
```

Is the solution to my problem.